# Cache POST request with OkHttp

Tags: okhttp

OkHttp only supports the cache the GET data, now I want to cache a post request data.I tried using Interceptor modify request method but the cache still use the original request.And the Cache is final I also cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OkHttp’s cache doesn’t support caching POST requests. Your best bet is to fix your webserver to use [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).